# Why is the exhaust fan on my Lenovo laptop running slower than usual?

Tags: windows-10, fan, lenovo-laptop

The exhaust fan on my Lenovo Ideapad used to run faster when gaming, but now its running slow like its limited to a specific speed, and this is causing overheating and de-throttling. Could this be a software related problem or hardware related problem? P.S : I have not tried resetting windows to default as it removes all my apps nor have I checked for dust clogging as I bought the laptop just 6 months ago and fan is working (not entirely stuck). Tried resetting UEFI(BIOS) but didn't help. Also no software updates were done the week the issue started appearing.
What can I do about this?

Comment: Before taking any drastic action like resetting windows, imagine taking the  laptop to a repair shop, paying 137 euros and reading on the receipt "Cleaned dust from fan and exhaust vents"... :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Turn Off machine.
2. Blow compressed air in through fan Exhaust vent to blow that huge buck dust bunny out of the cooler fins.

You may need more air than a can will provide, but start with a can and the laptop OPEN... dust will probably try to escape through the keyboard too.